# How to get URL using relative path?

Tags: java

I have a URL:

```
URL url=new URL("https://example.com/aa/bb/cc/file.html");
```

and a relative path:

```
String relativePath="../file2.html"; //maybe is "/file3.html"
```

I want to get `http://example.com/aa/bb/file2.html` using variable `url` and `relativePath`

How to do it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
new URL(url, relativePath);
```

Comment: +1. More details on the Java API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: No, the method exist since 1.0. Here's at least the doc for 1.3 (could not find 1.0 ;). http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: This resolves the relative URIs as per RFC2396, not as per RFC1808 as browsers seem to do. e.g. relative URI "?page=33" with base "http://site/path/list" will resolve differently.

Answer (score 11):

Try operating winth the class [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) instead of the [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

To get the URI from your URL:

```
java.net.URI anURI=url.toUri();
```

Then, to resolve the relative URI:

```
URI resultURI=anURI.resolve(relativePath);
```

And at last, to get an URL type use de method *toUrl()* of the URI result variable, and you've got it.

Comment: Why is it better to use URI than URL?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to build an URL pointing to a relative file, you can use:

```
URL url = new URL(new URL("file:"), "./myLocalFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

When building relative URL, keep in mind that the base is path to current package, not file. I mean: the referer file is in `.../myProject/src/pckg/javafile.java` and the referated file is in `.../myProject/some-other/nice.file`, then the relative reference should look like this:

```
URL url = new URL(new URL("file:"), "./../some-other/nice.file");
```

and this works for me as well:

```
URL url = new URL("file:./../some-other/nice.file");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if people noticed that the second form is the most interesting one. No need to split protocol and the rest

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked is this:

```
new URL("file:./src/gui/Something.fxml")
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for my code
`URL url=Myclass.class.getResource("/com/fnf/si/DepAcctInq_V02.wsdl");`