# Converting relative url to absolute url in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have written a scraper that fetches images from my clients feed. I have noticed that if the url is not absolute, I get 400 error (`Bad Request`) from the client. Does anyone know how to convert relative url to absolute url in Java?

This is my input url `https://www.sevilleclassics.com/../uploads/products/Bin-Rack.jpg` and my output url (absolute one) should look like `https://www.sevilleclassics.com/uploads/products/Bin-Rack.jpg` (difference is `/../uploads` vs `/uploads`)

Comment: `URI.normalize` is your friend

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer That won't remove the first `../` in this example.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665484/how-to-get-url-using-relative-path

Comment: it won't because there's nowhere to go, i.e. the URI is not valid for the server  (there are no more path segments that .. could be reduced for).
You need to get the correct base URL first.

Comment: btw, if you are scraping, there's a little known `<base>` tag that determines how relative URLs are resolved.

Comment: You need to solve it when you scrape see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144529/how-to-extract-absolute-url-from-relative-html-links-using-jsoup and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041676/how-to-resolve-relative-url-with-jsoup